# Double Tapped Gesture not working with addGestureRecognizer:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have an ImageView in that ImageView I displayed some images but when I tapped 2 times on that images i will not get the proper events.

this method not called.

```
- (void)doubleTapWebView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"double-tap");
    // nothing to do here
}
```

I tried this code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapWebView:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTap.delegate = self;
    [self.ImgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

and this is rest of the code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

    FrontsCards=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cloub1.png",@"cloub2.png",@"cloub3.png",@"cloub4.png", nil];

    for(int m=0; m< [FrontsCards count];m++)
    {

    //  int randIdx=arc4random()%[FrontsCards count];

        NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:m];

        NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];

        int padding=25;
        // padding is given.

        CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*m+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);

        ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

        [ImgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

        [scrollView addSubview:ImgView];
    }

    CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*[FrontsCards count], scrollView.frame.size.height);

    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default imageview userInteractio is false so you can add this line of code.

```
self.ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

And add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in .h file

Comment: @Jitendra Deore:where you are adding geastures in your code?may be before the image view allocation you are adding the gestures i think so.

Comment: add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in .h file and add gestures after allocation of the imageview then it'l works.

Comment: Already adding that UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in .h file but not happening any event.

Comment: i checked with this code it's working fine may be some where else you want wrong .

Comment: Solve my issue adding that UITapGestureRecognizer in for loop.

Comment: K fine that's why im asking in second comment where you are adding gestures in your code like that.

Comment: i you want to support me please help to increase my reputation.

Answer (score 2):

By default image's userinteraction is `NO`. So make it `YES`.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapWebView:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTap.delegate = self;
    [self.ImgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
self.ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, you're assigning each of the four image views to the same instance variable (`ImgView`).

At the end of the loop, `ImgView` will just point to the last one, so that's the one the gesture recognizer is added to. If you want to respond to double-tap events on every image view, you have to add a separate gesture recognizer to each of them. The easiest way to do this would be to add the recognizer(s) within your loop.

Also, as others have pointed out already, you need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for gesture recognizers to work on image views.

Btw, when you're iterating over the elements of an array (or collection in general), there's no need for a counter variable, just use `for (NSString *imageName in FrontCards) { ... }`. And the name of that variable should be `frontCards`; UpperCase names are conventionally reserved for class names.